# wpf dynamic border thickness binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, code-behind

I have a border generated dynamically.
I want to bind thickness property of it, with my style model.

```
Border db = new Border();                                                           
Binding borderthickness = new Binding();
borderthickness.Source = this.imodel.GridStyleProperties.BorderThickness;
borderthickness.Path = new PropertyPath("BorderThickness");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(db, Border.BorderThicknessProperty, borderthickness);
```

This is what I have done so far. Its not working for me.
Please suggest me what is wrong with this code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to a `BorderThickness` object, with `Path` set to `BorderThickness`. That means the binding will look in `this.imodel.GridStyleProperties.BorderThickness.BorderThickness` which doesn't exist.

Try

```
borderthickness.Source = this.imodel.GridStyleProperties;
borderthickness.Path = new PropertyPath("BorderThickness");
```

or just

```
borderthickness.Source = this.imodel.GridStyleProperties.BorderThickness;
```